# How we add numaric value of multiple cell of a datagridview?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

[image]

I create a datagridview for making a bill. Now I want add all column 4 values. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you tried to do? Show some code where you stack....

Comment: I want to add all cell value of 4th columns. And I want to get total amount.

Comment: From where you wan get values to `datagridview`? From `database` or you have some another `object` with values which you want show in datagridview?

Comment: @Fabio:: Those values are provided by user

Comment: If user input values manually in `datagridview` cells, then check @SenthilKumar's answer. `Datagridview` not provided a possibility having merge columns...

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then  // here your columnindex
            calctotal()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub calctotal()
        Dim tot As Single
        For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If rw.Cells(0).Value <> "" Then
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tot) Then
                    tot = Val(rw.Cells(0).Value) * Val(rw.Cells(1).Value)
                Else
                    tot = tot + Val(rw.Cells(0).Value) * Val(rw.Cells(1).Value)
                End If
                Label1.Text = tot
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```