# How to Calculate Subtotal for each item from datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql

I have table like this :

```
NAME ITEM COUNT
a     x     2
a     y     1
b     x     3
c     z     1
d     y     1
d     y     1
```

I have used this code to calculate total

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    }
```

How can I calculate sum for each item separately, result should be:

```
x=5
y=3
z=1
```

Comment: Are you looking for a c# solution or an Sql one? if it's an Sql solution, what database are you working with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417333/how-we-add-numaric-value-of-multiple-cell-of-a-datagridview/18418027#18418027

Comment: @Senthilkumar, Please describe a little about the link before populating it.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi sorry i will check that correct code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1) Loop through the datagrid.

2) Identify similar Item(like x,y and z) in loop and sum those.

```
int SumX=0;
int SumY=0;
int SumZ=0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
if(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == "x")
   sumX += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
else if(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == "y")
   sumY += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
else if(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == "z")
   sumZ += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
}
```

Here is an [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06c9727b-702f-447f-98e1-2d1ad1f09977/group-and-subtotal-within-a-datagridview?forum=vbgeneral).

Using LINQ query it's fairly straightforward.

```
int SumX = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Where(r=> Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["Item"].Value) == "x")
                    .Sum(t=> Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells["Count"].Value));
```

**Edit**

If you really want to make this summation dynamic then you can do something like this.Basically here is a dictionary to keep track of identical ITEM(s) and then sum the corresponding count.

```
    Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    string item = null;
    for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
            item = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            if (!dic.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                dic.Add(item, Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            }
            else
            {
                dic[item] += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            }

    }
```

Now you can loop through the dictionary and get the unique items count.

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> keyvalue in dic)
    {
       //get it here
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: What about `Z` column?

Comment: So, what if there is more cases in `ITEM` column? I think you should use a `group by`.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi I have posted an answer based on the exact use case OP provided.Now what you are telling is more practical scenario and yes the group by and sum has to be applied on data source level.

Comment: what will happen when a new Item `w` is introduced to the system? your solution would require a new build and publish...

Comment: @ZoharPeled you are right,I already mentioned in above comments,however based on your suggestion have updated the post now.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try following method to get a dictionary of grouped Item with summation:

```
private Dictionary<string, int> GetSummation()
{
    var kvp = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

    for (var i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.Trim();
        var count = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);

        kvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(item, count));
    }

    return kvp.GroupBy(k => k.Key).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(x => x.Value));
}
```